# Why the xgboost prediction values are different?

Tags: python, model, xgboost

I use the Python's xgboost library for my project. I use 8000 training samples and 2000 test samples to train a model. I get 0.91 and 0.92 accuracy.

But when I use only the first sample extracted from the training samples, I get a different prediction value from the previous prediction value by the trained model. Why does it like that?